# How to filter the cells with the date in between the other in excel

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to get all the tasks that are due in a week.
So column `A` is the names of the tasks, and column `M` is the due dates.

So my formula is this:

```
=FILTER(A10:A21;((M10:M21>=A1)*(M10:M21<=A2));"No data")
```

Where the `A1` is the beginning of the week and the `A2` is the end of the week.
But the issue is that it is getting all the tasks, even though it is over the date range.
Does someone have an idea what's happening?
Thanks a lot guys.

**Edited:**
Example of the table:

```
        A              M  
10  task name      Deadline
11  Task 1         10/01/2022
12  Task 2         11/01/2022
13  Task 3         12/01/2022
14  Task 4         13/01/2022
15  Task 5         14/01/2022
16  Task 6         15/01/2022
17  Task 7         16/01/2022
18  Task 8         09/01/2022
19  Task 9         18/01/2022
20  Task 10        01/01/2022
21  Task 11        20/01/2022
```

The date is in format dd/mm/yyyy.
The start date I'm using is 10/01/2022 in cell A1
The end date I'm using is 16/01/2022 in cell A2
The formula I used with commas doesn't work.
And it is returning the tasks from 1 to 11

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sufficient information so your problem can be reproduced. It might help for you to read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel are you using. After replacing the semi-colon by comma as follow it worked just fine with MS 365.

```
=FILTER(A10:A37,((M10:M37>=A1)*(M10:M37<=A2)),"No data")
```

Comment: I'm using ms 365. But I'm in linux

Comment: Very useful information.  Go in the option menu, advanced tab and select "Use 1904 date format", it might just do trick.
Your date for calculation are most likely 1462 days in the past, hence all due.